# C# Sharepoint.client : file.TimeLastModified, get GMT instead of time displayed on SP Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Not exactly a question but just would like to share that while trying to filter a list of files retrieved by last modified date, I was having issue getting the correct return.

I used file.TimeLastModified to filter files that are modified in the last hour in a SPO folder. However it return 0 count when I was expecting 5.

```
        DateTime lastHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
        var items = folder.Files.Where(file => file.TimeLastModified > lastHour);
```

Turns out the file.TimeLastModified return time in GMT instead, which I need to factor in the my local time different to correct the logic.

It's kind of weird because in SPO library, local time is displayed for the same field.

Hope this post can help someone someday.